# How to retrieve the user's profile and the user's calendars using the Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I can retrieve a user's profile using Microsoft Graph API and as well as their calendars in my web application. Sometimes, I have to get them in one request; such as the network is too slow or some reason. However, there is not a property about the calendars in the response of this API `GET /me`.How can I deal with this?

I use the following code using the Graph Client:

```
// get the user's profile
var me = await _serviceClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();

// list the user's calendars
var result = _serviceClient.Me.Calendars.Request().GetAsync();
```

Anyone can help me? Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you have tried the `batch` endpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I assume you want to get the user's profile and list his profile in one request.

Refer to [this document](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/json_batching), we can using the following API to do it.

```
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$batch`
```

And we can put the two requests in the body, like this:

```
`{
  "requests": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "/me"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "/me/calendars"
    }
    ]
}`
```

We can get the result like this (the screenshot had be truncated for brevity)
[image: The result]

Comment: It exactly what I need. Thank for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Graph, at its core, is an API Aggregator. In other words, it acts as a proxy for multiple product APIs (Azure Active Directory, Exchange Online, SharePoint, OneDrive, OneNote, etc.). In general, you cannot retrieve data across API boundaries.

In this case, `/me` is pulling data from Azure Active Directory while `/calendars` is pulling from Exchange Online. As such, you cannot retrieve both result sets from a single call.

You can use [JSON Batching](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/json_batching) to approximate a single call but I'm not sure it will make much of a difference. The overhead of two calls vs. one is pretty minimal, and the size of the results should be nearly identical regardless. JSON Batching allows you to make a single call but it requires a slightly larger request payload (the JSON to execute) and, again, the result size should be identical to two calls). I'd expect any performance difference to be negligible at best.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got a lot form your answer.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Marc's comments, you shouldn't assume that batching is the fastest solution because HTTP requests can be issued in parallel.  It does take a bit of futzing around with Tasks but there is no reason multiple calls need to be executed sequentially.

Here's an timeline from Fiddler of a batch call doing the same thing as the two other calls.

[image]